# React - can't get DOM to pull in the latest data when posted from a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios

[My codesandbox.io demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sample-vjl5e?file=/index.js)

New to react and I'm having a difficult time understanding the lifecycles, and at what point the DOM rerenders. In my demo in the link above, I can add and delete my records and the DOM updates perfectly. The problem I'm running into is when I add data from a child component (a modal), I can't get the DOM to rerender the latest change until the next lifecycle occurs.

To be specific, I'm passing in a functional prop to the child. When the prop is fired from the child, I'm running a function in the parent to pull data from a server and set the state to this data.

```
        <Modal
          changeValue={changeValue}
        />
```

In the child component, when a form is submitted it posts the data to the server, then invokes this functional prop.

```
  createNote = e => {
    //POST DATA TO SERVER HERE
    this.props.changeValue();
  };
```

And here is the function it fires in the parent component:

```
    const changeValue = () => {
      this.getNotes();
    };
```

getNotes() gets the data from the server and sets the state. However when this is invoked by the child it misses out on the DOM render.

In my demo, you can test both ways of adding data. The first works just as it's supposed to, but running the same form from the modal is where I'm having trouble.

[CODESANDBOX DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sample-vjl5e?file=/index.js)

Comment: I examine your code now but you write so complex. I think, maybe you can be missing calbacks function parent to child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call getNotes() again after crud operation.
For example, after createNote(), you can get id from the return of post, then append the new Note object to notearray.

```
createNote = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.notevalue) {
     const newNote = {notevalue: this.state.notevalue,
      notedate: this.state.notedate};
      axios
        .post("https://prccrm-65ae7.firebaseio.com/admin/notes.json", newNote)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          this.setState({notesarray : [{
            noteid: response.data.name,
            ...newNote           
          }, ...this.state.notesarray]});
          //this.getNotes();
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
    // document.getElementById("txtid-note").value = "";
    this.setState({ notevalue: "" });
  };
```

Comment: I think this is what I'd like to do, but how would I append the new note to notearray from the child component? I'm thinking it will involve two way binding but not sure the best practice.

Comment: You can pass createNote function to child component, then use this function in child component to update parent's note array. Example demo code here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sample-sigqe

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it to work doing what you suggested! I just passed the child's state through .bind(this) Updated my sandbox as well. Appreciate you nudging me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to write the solutions...
I checked your code and there is no code to sync remote data after modal submit.

1. You can use SWR or react-query
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/swr
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query

Hooks for fetching, caching and updating asynchronous data

2. You can use redux.

Comment: Thanks! I'm close to doing my redux studies but haven't gotten there yet.